# Python Register Account model

Tags: javascript, python, hash, passwords

I'm sure this has been asked before, however I've been searching for hours and cannot find anything that works so apologies in advance. I'm in the early stages of learning to code with Python on an online course and I'm deviating away from it a little to make it my own.

When a user registers an account, I want to return an error if the username is already taken. Otherwise to create the account and redirect to the login page. However I'm not sure how to do define the if statement to return the correct console response as it only currently returns the user. I want this to return success / error and use ajax to catch this response.

The register model I have so far is:

```
class RegisterModel:

    def __init__(self):
        self.client = MongoClient()
        self.db = self.client.codewizard
        self.Users = self.db.users

    def insert_user(self, data):
        existing_user = self.Users.find_one({"username": data.username})
        if existing_user:
            pymsgbox.native.alert('Username already taken!', 'Title')
        else:
            hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(data.password.encode(), bcrypt.gensalt())

            id = self.Users.insert({"username": data.username, "name": data.name, "password": hashed, "email": data.email})
            print("uid is", id)

            pymsgbox.native.alert('Account created, please login!', 'Title')
```

And the controller:

```
class PostRegistration:
    def POST(self):
        data = web.input()

        reg_model = RegisterModel.RegisterModel()
        reg_model.insert_user(data)

        return data.username
```

and finally the javascript (not completed with if statement)

```js
 $(document).on("submit", "#register-form", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $('#register-form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/postregistration',
        type: 'POST',
        data: form,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

`pymsgbox` will be replaced by the Javascript when I can get it to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

Controller:

```
class PostRegistration:
def POST(self):
    data = web.input()

    reg_model = RegisterModel.RegisterModel()
    register = reg_model.insert_user(data)
    if register:
        return register
```

and then returning "error" in the register model `if` statement.